# How can I use system.web as a configuration section in a asp.net net472 app that uses System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I am migrating a large .net framework application to net6.  The strategy I am using is to migrate libraries to netstandard2.0 while keeping the net472 runtime until the application is ready to migrate completely.

As part of the process, I need to upgrade from System.Configuration (only net472) to System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager (netstandard2.0) version 6.0.0.  However, when I update all references in my code, my ASP.net web service running returns this error:

```
Unrecognized configuration section system.web
```

Some details:

1. ASP.Net application is running on IIS
2. IIS is using some of the settings in the system.web section of the configuration
3. ASP.Net application is running on the netframework 4.7.2 (not netcore/net6)
4. If I include System.Configuration as well, then it fails on a DLL mismatch.  If I don't, I get this error

How can I get my application to retrieve the configuration and not fail on this error?

Comment: .NET Framework always used ConfigurationManager, all the way back to .NET 1. Your web service already uses it. The `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` isn't an upgrade, it's a compatibility package for .NET *Core or Standard* projects that need to work with legacy settings. It shouldn't be added to .NET Framework projects, it's already there. If it was added to your ASP.NET service, it should be removed

Comment: Thank you.  I realized that issue was that it was pulling in the netstandard2.0 version of System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager in the executable bin folder.  I switched it to the net461 dll and it works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Panagiotis Kanavos for the direction.

The issue was that in the bin folder of the executable, I was using the netstandard2.0 version of the library.  I had to change it to pull down the net461 version and then everything ran fine.

Comment: How did you change which version it was "pulling down"?

Comment: In my case, it was a net472 web application. NuGet references are listed in packages.config, and then as a regular reference with a path in the project file. I updated the HintPath in the project file to point to the net461 folder in the NuGet package and it worked fine